# How to avoid to duplicate a subquery in a query

Tags: sql-server, subquery

I'm running a query that contains the same subquery two times, one used in a inner join condition and the another in a outer join. I'm highlighting the repeated subquery with **. How can I optimize this in order to run only once?

```
SELECT DISTINCT dbo.tb_contato.Nome, dbo.tb_contato.id_contato, dbo.tb_contato.Sexo, dbo.tb_contato.codigo, dbo.tb_email.email
FROM         dbo.tb_contato INNER JOIN
                      dbo.tb_email ON dbo.tb_contato.id_contato = dbo.tb_email.id_contato INNER JOIN
                      dbo.tb_empresa ON dbo.tb_empresa.id_empresa = dbo.tb_contato.id_empresa LEFT OUTER JOIN
                          (SELECT     dbo.tb_interacao.IDContato AS id_contato
                            FROM          dbo.tb_interacao INNER JOIN
                                                       **(SELECT     MAX(IDInteracao) AS IDIntMax, IDPerfilParticipante AS id_perfil_participante, IDProjeto, IDContato
                                                         FROM          dbo.tb_interacao AS tb_interacao_2
                                                         GROUP BY IDPerfilParticipante, IDProjeto, IDContato)** AS IntMax1 ON dbo.tb_interacao.IDInteracao = IntMax1.IDIntMax INNER JOIN
                                                   dbo.tb_projeto ON dbo.tb_interacao.IDProjeto = dbo.tb_projeto.id_projeto INNER JOIN
                                                   dbo.tb_status_processo ON dbo.tb_interacao.IDStatusProcesso = dbo.tb_status_processo.id_status_processo
                            WHERE      (dbo.tb_projeto.id_projeto = 2057) AND (dbo.tb_interacao.IDPerfilParticipante = 1) AND (dbo.tb_status_processo.id_status_processo = 7) OR
                                                   (dbo.tb_projeto.id_projeto = 2057) AND (dbo.tb_interacao.IDPerfilParticipante = 1) AND (dbo.tb_status_processo.id_status_processo = 6) OR
                                                   (dbo.tb_interacao.IDPerfilParticipante = 1) AND (dbo.tb_status_processo.id_status_processo = 6) AND (dbo.tb_projeto.id_grupo = 55) OR
                                                   (dbo.tb_interacao.IDPerfilParticipante = 1) AND (dbo.tb_status_processo.id_status_processo = 7) AND (dbo.tb_projeto.id_grupo = 55)) 
                      AS ConvidadosOut ON dbo.tb_contato.id_contato = ConvidadosOut.id_contato INNER JOIN
                          (SELECT     tb_interacao_1.IDContato AS id_contato
                            FROM          dbo.tb_interacao AS tb_interacao_1 INNER JOIN
                                                       **(SELECT     MAX(IDInteracao) AS IDIntMax, IDPerfilParticipante AS id_perfil_participante, IDProjeto, IDContato
                                                         FROM          dbo.tb_interacao AS tb_interacao_3
                                                         GROUP BY IDPerfilParticipante, IDProjeto, IDContato)** AS IntMax2 ON tb_interacao_1.IDInteracao = IntMax2.IDIntMax INNER JOIN
                                                   dbo.tb_projeto AS tb_projeto_1 ON tb_interacao_1.IDProjeto = tb_projeto_1.id_projeto INNER JOIN
                                                   dbo.tb_status_processo AS tb_status_processo_1 ON tb_interacao_1.IDStatusProcesso = tb_status_processo_1.id_status_processo
                            WHERE      (tb_projeto_1.id_projeto = 181) AND (IntMax2.id_perfil_participante = 1) AND (tb_status_processo_1.id_status_processo = 4) OR
                                                   (tb_projeto_1.id_projeto = 1581) AND (IntMax2.id_perfil_participante = 1) AND (tb_status_processo_1.id_status_processo = 5) OR
                                                   (IntMax2.id_perfil_participante = 1) AND (tb_status_processo_1.id_status_processo = 6) AND (tb_projeto_1.id_grupo = 62)) AS ConvidadosIn ON 
                      dbo.tb_contato.id_contato = ConvidadosIn.id_contato
WHERE     (dbo.tb_email.email_visibility = 0 OR
                      dbo.tb_email.email_visibility IS NULL) AND (dbo.tb_empresa.id_pais = 1) AND (dbo.tb_contato.Fonte <> 'salesloft_orange' AND 
                      dbo.tb_contato.Fonte <> 'salesloft_int_orange' OR
                      dbo.tb_contato.Fonte IS NULL) AND (dbo.tb_contato.id_contato_visibility = 1 OR
                      dbo.tb_contato.id_contato_visibility IS NULL) AND (ConvidadosOut.id_contato IS NULL)
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope you are using SQL server 2005 or later. You can safely try using Common table expressions for the purpose as stated in your question.
Below is an example of script from adventureworks database:

```
USE AdventureWorks2008R2;
GO
-- Define the CTE expression name and column list.
WITH Sales_CTE (SalesPersonID, SalesOrderID, SalesYear)
AS
-- Define the CTE query.
(
    SELECT SalesPersonID, SalesOrderID, YEAR(OrderDate) AS SalesYear
    FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader
    WHERE SalesPersonID IS NOT NULL
)
-- Define the outer query referencing the CTE name.
SELECT SalesPersonID, COUNT(SalesOrderID) AS TotalSales, SalesYear
FROM Sales_CTE
GROUP BY SalesYear, SalesPersonID
ORDER BY SalesPersonID, SalesYear;
GO
```

Comment: sounds a good idea, but I'm not sure how to use CTE in two selects. I haven't found any examples where I call the CTE twice. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: You can call CTE as many times as you want if it is just called within same query. You can check the multiple CTE usage within same query by Pinal Dave at http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/08/08/sql-server-multiple-cte-in-one-select-statement-query/

Comment: Thank you Kasim. It worked, but the processing time is the same. Shouldn't it get faster once I'm running the CTE only once?

Comment: CTE is helpful only for ease of scripting. During execution time the CTE is replaced in the final query, so the execution plan for both your original script and the script with CTE will be exactly same. In case you would like to gain on performance, you may consider using table variable.